# realmdb auto-updating and persistent storage

Tags: xamarin, realm

[You documentation on auto updating objects](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#auto-updating-objects)

This is only updating the in memory instance of the object and NOT persisting it to storage ... correct?

Comment: what do you mean? `Realm.Write` writes to the database, that is why it's called `Write`.

Answer (score 2):

> the in memory instance of the object

Managed RealmObjects are proxies to the underlying database.

Managed RealmObjects are "immutable" outside of write transactions (apart from when they are synced to the Realm's latest version).

Which means, managed RealmObjects can only be modified inside a write transaction.

> and NOT persisting it to storage ... correct?

Any mutable change to a managed RealmObject in a write transaction is directly written to the database, although this "new version" in which the RealmObject has been written to is persisted as the "new latest version" only if the write transaction is committed.

---

```
realm.Write(() => 
{
    myPuppy.Age = 2;
}          // <--- end of block is auto-commit on success (no exceptions)
```

This means that modifying the in-memory instance inside a write transaction **will persist it to the storage as well**.